# Resetting backoff for 'Package Name'

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Hello I have created an android application in that I wants to GCM Register id.

My code is-

```
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);      
    if (regId.equals("")) 
    {
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
    }

    Log.v("REG ID:",""+regId);
```

But it gives error like-

```
Resetting backoff for 'Package Name'
```

What is meaning of this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added the following Permission and Kindly check whether your Sender Id is in Live or not.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

 <permission android:name="com.example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your GCMIntentService is not well defined ?

Please check out this:)

[I can not get registration ID from Android GCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713363/i-can-not-get-registration-id-from-android-gcm)