# GCM response NotRegistered after one hour

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, response, infobip

I have a problem with my application. About sending notifications via GCM. My application saves on my server the user register_id, notifications work perfect, but after an hour I get error NotRegistered.

I have reviewed the documentation and in theory the REQUEST should return me a new register_id, but this does not happen.

Can I get help?

Comment: It may help to paste relevant code in your question.

Comment: Do you have `GCMIntentService` defined correctly in your Android manifest file ? You might want to check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11736123/4195406)

Answer (score 2):

Based on your Manifest file, I suppose that you are using https://github.com/infobip/push-plugin-cordova-phonegap insted of https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.

Here is a [documentation](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.infobip.push.cordova) for Infobip Push Library. Let's try to integrate it from scratch, but first of all, don't forget to register on [Push Platform](https://push.infobip.com) and get necessary credentials.