# Android - not getting GCM token

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I call `RegistrationIntentService`:

```
    if (checkPlayServices()) {
        Log.i("udazzT", "check servicies");
        // Start IntentService to register this application with GCM.
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
        startService(intent2);
    }
```

But I cannot see any of the logs in RegistrationIntentService:

```
public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "RegIntentService";
    private static final String[] TOPICS = {"global"};

    public RegistrationIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.i("udazzT", "setting token");
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        try {
            // In the (unlikely) event that multiple refresh operations occur simultaneously,
            // ensure that they are processed sequentially.
            synchronized (TAG) {
                // [START register_for_gcm]
                // Initially this call goes out to the network to retrieve the token, subsequent calls
                // are local.
                // [START get_token]
                Log.i("udazzT", "setting token 2");
                InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
                String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                        GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
                // [END get_token]
                Log.i(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);

                // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
                sendRegistrationToServer(token);

                // Subscribe to topic channels
                subscribeTopics(token);

                // You should store a boolean that indicates whether the generated token has been
                // sent to your server. If the boolean is false, send the token to your server,
                // otherwise your server should have already received the token.
                sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, true).apply();
                // [END register_for_gcm]
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
            // If an exception happens while fetching the new token or updating our registration data
            // on a third-party server, this ensures that we'll attempt the update at a later time.
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false).apply();
        }
        // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
        Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(QuickstartPreferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
    }

    /**
     * Persist registration to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's GCM registration token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }

    /**
     * Subscribe to any GCM topics of interest, as defined by the TOPICS constant.
     *
     * @param token GCM token
     * @throws IOException if unable to reach the GCM PubSub service
     */
    // [START subscribe_topics]
    private void subscribeTopics(String token) throws IOException {
        for (String topic : TOPICS) {
            GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);
            pubSub.subscribe(token, "/topics/" + topic, null);
        }
    }
    // [END subscribe_topics]

}
```

Comment: Have you read through this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713363/i-can-not-get-registration-id-from-android-gcm?

Comment: The register method in that example is deprecated

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure that it is registered in your manifest.

```
<service android:name=".RegistrationIntentService"
             android:exported="false" />
```

Comment: @MarianoPelizzari are you seeing the log output before the intent? `Log.i("udazzT", "check servicies");`

Comment: Yes I'm seen that one

Comment: Try including an intent filter with this: `<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />`

Comment: I started a new project and the problem was fixed with `<service android:name=".RegistrationIntentService"
             android:exported="false" />`

Comment: In my case I put the RegistrationIntentService inside a package called .gcm, so the IDE in Android studio made it like so:
<service android:name=".gcm.RegistrationIntentService"... /> and that is why it did not work in my case. What I had to do was to put a full reference to it: <service android:name="com.mycompany.gcm.RegistrationIntentService"...  /> And now it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Did you think to add all is needed like here [googlesamples](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/MainActivity.java)

Comment: I did, and I reviewed several times

Comment: ok because I forgot some methods, but now it works for me with googlesamples.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
<category android:name="<PACKAGE-NAME>" />
</intent-filter>
```

in manifest.xml of "GcmReceiver" & "MyGcmListenerService"   in my code it is looks like below.

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="<PACKAGE-NAME>" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- [END gcm_receiver] -->

    <!-- [START gcm_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name="<PACKAGE-NAME>.MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="<PACKAGE-NAME>" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END gcm_listener] -->
    <!-- [START instanceId_listener] -->
```

In my case it is working... May be it will be helpful to you.  Best Of Luck

Answer (score 0):

check if you have added below line in receivers intent filter

Since its mentioned in GCM doc as:

If you want to support pre-4.4 KitKat devices, add the following action to the intent filter declaration for the receiver:

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest